# Nested array in drop down

Tags: json, nested, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

I'm new to angular js, so maybe it is a trivial thing, but somehow I cannot get the hang of it. I have an array of objects and in each object there is another array of objects as:

```
filteredList=[{Company : "IBX", CEO : "ABC", HeadOffice : "US" ,locations : [{Location : "US", RegionalCEO : "ABC"},{Location : "India", RegionalCEO : "CDE"},{Location : "UK", RegionalCEO : "FGH"}]},{Company : "Micr$",HeadOffice : "US", CEO : "Gill", locations : [{Location : "US", RegionalCEO : "Gill"},{Location : "India", RegionalCEO : "QWE"},{Location : "Singapore", RegionalCEO : "XYX"},{Location : "Aus", RegionalCEO : "ZEB"}]},{Company : "Inf",HeadOffice : "India", CEO : "NMrt", locations : [{Location : "India", RegionalCEO : "Nmrt"},{Location : "US", RegionalCEO : "PhM"},{Location : "Denmark", RegionalCEO : "Zyqes"},{Location : "Philipines", RegionalCEO : "Pinesad"},{Location : "Taiwan", RegionalCEO : "Abur"},{Location : "UAE", RegionalCEO : "Abuf"}]}]
```

There are more properties, but in the interest of time, I am posting just important ones.
So I need to populate dropdowns with locations (UK, US, India, UAE, Philipines, etc.) and RegionalCEO.

What i have tried is following:

```
 < select name="locations" ng-model="locat" ng-options="item.Location for item in filteredList[0].locations"></select >
```

The above code does not display all values, as I suspected, then I tried the below, after reading few posts:

```
<select name="locations">
<option ng-repeat-start ="locations in filteredList">
</option>
<option ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="Location in locations" value="{ Location}">{Location}</option>

</select>
```

This displays empty drop down!!!!

Am I trying something impossible? :) The data cannot be modified as it is provided from another source.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit of mistake there, first you need to understand that ng-repeat simply iterates over your data like in a for loop. so suppose you want to extract the location from the given array by using for loop. the code for that would be

```
for( var i = 0;i< filteredList.length; i++){
         currentItem = filteredList[i]; 
         //when i=0,  current item = {Company : "IBX", CEO : "ABC", HeadOffice : "US" ,locations : [{Location : "US", RegionalCEO : "ABC"},{Location : "India", RegionalCEO : "CDE"},{Location : "UK", RegionalCEO : "FGH"}]}

         //now extract the locations
         var locationsArray = currentItem.locations;
         for( var j = 0 ;j < locationsArray.length ; j++ ){
                 var location = locationsArray[j].Location; 
                 //for j=0 , location = "US"  
         }
}
```

now use this logic in ng-repeat.

```
    <select name="locations">
    <option ng-repeat-start ="item in filteredList">
    <option ng-repeat-end  ng-repeat="location in item.locations" value="{{ location.Location}}">{{location.Location}}</option>
    </option>

    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks rdRahul. Unfortunately this does not work. The page becomes unresponsive because the inner array has more than 100 objects and outer array is 300 long,, not sure if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Use array [**map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to fetch the nested array from the array of objects.You will get all three `locations` array by using this method.
- Use array [**concat()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method to merge the nested arrays on which you want to apply `ng-repeat`.So, that all the objects from different `locations` array merge into an single array.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    var filteredList = [{
 Company: "IBX",
 CEO: "ABC",
 HeadOffice: "US",
 locations: [{
  Location: "US",
  RegionalCEO: "ABC"
 }, {
  Location: "India",
  RegionalCEO: "CDE"
 }, {
  Location: "UK",
  RegionalCEO: "FGH"
 }]
}, {
 Company: "Micr$",
 HeadOffice: "US",
 CEO: "Gill",
 locations: [{
  Location: "US",
  RegionalCEO: "Gill"
 }, {
  Location: "India",
  RegionalCEO: "QWE"
 }, {
  Location: "Singapore",
  RegionalCEO: "XYX"
 }, {
  Location: "Aus",
  RegionalCEO: "ZEB"
 }]
}, {
 Company: "Inf",
 HeadOffice: "India",
 CEO: "NMrt",
 locations: [{
  Location: "India",
  RegionalCEO: "Nmrt"
 }, {
  Location: "US",
  RegionalCEO: "PhM"
 }, {
  Location: "Denmark",
  RegionalCEO: "Zyqes"
 }, {
  Location: "Philipines",
  RegionalCEO: "Pinesad"
 }, {
  Location: "Taiwan",
  RegionalCEO: "Abur"
 }, {
  Location: "UAE",
  RegionalCEO: "Abuf"
 }]
}];

var locationsArr = filteredList.map(function(item) {
  return item.locations;
});

$scope.finalArr = locationsArr[0].concat(locationsArr[1]).concat(locationsArr[2]);



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<select name="locations">
<option ng-repeat="locations in finalArr">
{{locations.Location}}
</option>
<option ng-repeat="locations in finalArr">{{locations.RegionalCEO}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @r-j but data I gave is an example. Although this would work if know the length of data , in this case 3 , what happens when outer array is 500+ and inner array is 100+ for each item ?

Comment: I only used the same data as provided by you in the post.